# what is the relation between 32 bit and 4GB memory?

Tags: c, memory, 32-bit

I understand that a 32 bit OS can have 2^32 memory location and 2^32 is almost equal to 4 billion. But why the memory is 4GB? 1 byte is 8 bits and on each memory location there are 4 bytes = 32 bit. So 2 ^ 32 times 4 should equal to 4 * 4 * (2 ^ 30) = 16 GB?

Comment: No each memory location is byte addressable, it's one byte.

Comment: Because memory locations are 1 byte, not 4 bytes.

Comment: Addresses are byte addresses. You can address up to 4 billion bytes or 2 billion 16-bit values or 1 billion 32-bit values, using billion in the sense of 'binary billion'.

Answer (score 1):

2^32 bytes = 4294967296 bytes = 4194304 KB = 4096 MB = 4GB.

A 32-bit OS uses 32-bit pointers.  The largest value that can point to is 2^32 - 1.  So a 32-bit OS can only see 4GB of memory.